# Lightbox close button rollover effect

Tags: lightbox

Ok, not really seeing any previous help for this one specifically. What I want to do is have a "hover" effect for the close button. I have got it to where when you hover over the the close button itself it will display and go away when you move the mouse out. But, what I want is when you hover over the image being displayed in the lightbox I want the close button to display and when you mouseout I want the close button to disappear.

Also, some pointers for using the transitions effects or sources for that would be good. I am still a student working on portfolio pieces. I graduate in August 2013.

All help is appreciated =) I am also researching on my own, but not all of what I am reading is working or making sense. I am coming into places like this and Yahoo! Answers for extra help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to Lightview was well configured.

You can download here:
http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/lightview